# Which Dialogflow entity type to set for multi space separated user phrase for account name

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am building new intent where user phrases contains company name, like,

my company is google

Google Technology is my company

company is Apple Systems Inc.

What could BE entity type i have to set to get complete company name as is in user phrases. Like for above phrases, i want dialog flow would give me,

1. google
2. Google Technology
3. Apple Systems Inc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much control you have (or want) about what those company names can be.

If you have a concrete list of companies that it should apply to, you can [create a Custom Entity Type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-custom). This is the best approach if you can use it.

If not, you may need to use the `@sys.any` type, which will match anything.

Comment: I tried sys.any  but its working only for the company name that i added in user phrases. Not for anything new company string

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you update your original question to include screen shots of your Intent, including training phrases and parameters, and sample phrases that illustrate what isn't working?